# How to limit ForeignKey field to another model FK depending on value

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-smart-selects

I have the following models in Django, and using smart-selects:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
```

In the fixtures, i added multiple countries, with their provinces, and cities.

I'm using [smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) for chaining in this model

```
class WorkArea(models.Model):
    work_area = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    province =  ChainedForeignKey(Province, chained_field="country",chained_model_field="country")
    city = ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field=province", chained_model_field="province")
```

Now i have this model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
```

The question: In the model `Project` how do i show only provinces form `Province` model, that has `country` set to X (If i have countries "USA" and "Canada" i want the field `province` to show list of provinces in "USA" only, with preselecting country).

Comment: I suppose you want that with Javascript so that when user select one  country, all province of that country are automatically listed?

Comment: No, in the model `Project` at the field `province` i want it to show list of USA provinces only. as you can see in the model `WorkArea` i already implemented the smart-selects plugin and it work perfect. my issue in the `Project` model, that i don't want the user to choose the country, it must be pre-selected as "USA" or pk=x, so there won't be `country` field in this model.

Comment: I haven't used that package before, thanks for sharing.
I have upvoted and stared your question, hopefully someone else can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution using `limit_choices_to`

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, limit_choices_to={"country": 1})
```